# Auto Increment of RateNumber

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables:

1) BlogPost:

```
 COLUMN_NAME    DATA_TYPE
Id                  int
Title             varchar
Description       varchar
ImageName         varchar
FileName          varchar
CreatedDate       datetime
Tags              varchar
ModifiedDate      datetime
RateNumber           int
CreatedBy            int
ShortDescription    varchar
```

2. BlogRating:

```
Id  EmployeeId  PostId  Rate
4     1           12    3
5     1           13    2
6     1           11    2
```

I wrote a stored procedure to Save the details of BlogRating:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BlogRatingSave]
     @EmployeeId    int
    ,@PostId        int
    ,@Rate          int
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM [HRM_BlogRating]
        WHERE   [HRM_BlogRating].[EmployeeId] = @EmployeeId 
            AND [HRM_BlogRating].[PostId] = @PostId 

    INSERT INTO [HRM_BlogRating]
        ([EmployeeId]
        ,[PostId]
        ,[Rate]
        )
    VALUES
        (@EmployeeId    
        ,@PostId        
        ,@Rate
        )
END
```

What I want is that If different employees give rate, while saving BlogRating I need to auto increment the field RateNumber in table1by 1. At the same time if same employee rates next time there should not an increment for RateNumber. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you deleting and then inserting. Instead you should try to insert and if it fails (due to a duplicate) then do an update.

In the process you can also adjust the value of the rating, but I assume you will need to pass in the EmployeeId of the person making the change since that is part of your rule. ie.

```
update BlogPost set RateNumber = RateNumber + 1 where EmployeeId = @EmployeeID and CreatedBy != @EmployeeID
```

So it would all become:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BlogRatingSave]
     @EmployeeId    int
    ,@PostId        int
    ,@Rate          int
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO [HRM_BlogRating]
            ([EmployeeId]
            ,[PostId]
            ,[Rate]
            )
        VALUES
            (@EmployeeId    
            ,@PostId        
            ,@Rate
            )
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        UPDATE [HRM_BlogRating]
             SET Rate = @Rate
        WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID and PostId = @PostId
    END CATCH

    UPDATE BlogPost set RateNumber = RateNumber + 1 where EmployeeId = @EmployeeID and CreatedBy != @EmployeeID
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I try this one as solution? @Michael

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BlogRatingSave]
     @EmployeeId    int
    ,@PostId        int
    ,@Rate          int
AS
BEGIN
IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [HRM_BlogRating] WHERE EmployeeId= @EmployeeId AND [PostId] = @PostId))
    BEGIN
        DELETE 
            FROM 
                [HRM_BlogRating]
        WHERE   
                [HRM_BlogRating].[EmployeeId]=@EmployeeId  
            AND 
                [HRM_BlogRating].[PostId] = @PostId 
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE 
            HRM_BlogPost 
        SET 
            RateNumber=isnull(RateNumber,0)+1 
        WHERE 
            Id=@PostId
    END 

    INSERT INTO [HRM_BlogRating]
        ([EmployeeId]
        ,[PostId]
        ,[Rate]
        )
    VALUES
        (@EmployeeId    
        ,@PostId        
        ,@Rate
        )
END
```

Comment: Can I try this one as solution? @Michael

Comment: That's okay I, but a select plus a delete plus an update (in your example) would be slower than an attempted insert then an update (in mine). I thought you also only wanted to update BlogPost if it was a different EmployeeId.